# iOS - audio sync and delay for AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem, how to detect startup delay

Tags: ios, synchronization, delay, avplayer, latency

I'm playing one file, while recording another. Ideally, later, I want to play them both back, with exactly the same sync as the user experienced when they were watching the first clip. That is, the audio playing in clip 1, which was recorded by clip 2, should match (not echo) when both clips are playing at the same time. I know this will never happen, so I will be muting clip 1, but playing it's video. I want clip 1's video to match the audio in clip 2... That's the goal.

So, much easier issue: Let's assume I have prerolled an AVPlayer(Item)... When I press 'play', how can I programmatically tell how long it will take the clip to reach the screen and speaker? Is this determined by the audio buffering delay in the AVPlayer(Item)? or is it also determined by something in the kernel? audio driver? Anyhow: is there a way I can measure it? This will get me a lot closer to my goal, right now the two clips are off by about 250ms.

I was told by somebody to use addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes, and watch when it crosses over time zero. This doesn't work. But if I cue the clip, and set the boundary to 1 second, I get called approximately 1050ms later. I don't know if the 50ms delay is because of loose timing in the callback system, or because there is actually a startup delay of 50ms, or if it's something else.